# Creating required SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, window-functions

My next question is about creating SQL script as required. Here is my wish:
I want to select **ID** and **DOC** columns from my **TEST1** table where the difference(subtraction) between two consecutive operations over **ID** column is less than three minutes. Here is my creating table and inserting test dates script:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1(ID NUMBER , DOC CHAR(2), C_TIME TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(100,'A1',timestamp '2020-09-27 13:20:43');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(100,'A2',timestamp '2020-09-27 13:21:12');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(100,'A3',timestamp '2020-09-27 13:25:40');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(101,'A1',timestamp '2020-09-27 14:12:20');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(101,'A2',timestamp '2020-09-27 14:20:32');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(102,'A1',timestamp '2020-09-27 11:10:54');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(102,'A2',timestamp '2020-09-27 14:30:52');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(102,'A3',timestamp '2020-09-27 15:21:15');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(103,'A1',timestamp '2020-09-27 17:41:11');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(103,'A2',timestamp '2020-09-27 17:42:56');
INSERT INTO TEST1(ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES(103,'A3',timestamp '2020-09-27 17:44:01');
COMMIT;
```

So, my required output will be green rows:

[image]

Comment: Why `SELECT .. from dual`? Just do `INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES (100,'A1', TO_DATE('2020-09-27 13:20:43','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: or, since we have a timestamp, `INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID,DOC,C_TIME) VALUES (100,'A1', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-27 13:20:43')`

Comment: You expect `100 A1` but not `101 A1` and `102 A1` but again you want `103 A1`. What is the logic here ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I don't expect `101 A1` because **c_time** of `101 A2` subtract **c_time** of `101 A1` is more than 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you not only require previous row value using `lag` but in case of first record for an id the difference in time should also be checked with the next row using `lead` and then finally subtract and check the difference,

```
select t.id,t.doc,t.c_time
from (
    select t.*
         , lag(c_time,1) over(partition by id order by c_time) lag_c_time
         , lead(c_time,1) over(partition by id order by c_time) lead_c_time
    from test1 t
) t
where abs(extract( minute from (c_time - coalesce(lag_c_time,lead_c_time)))) < 3
```

Comment: Yes you are great , Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, lag(c_time) over(partition by id order by c_time) lag_c_time
    from test1 t
) t
where c_time < lag_c_time + interval '3' minute or lag_c_ctime is null
```

It is unclear whether you want to first row per id or not. The above query brings it - if you don't, just remove condition `lag_c_time is null` from the `where` clause.

Comment: Hi dear @GMB I have tried this one but it didn't returns me the second row, evean if i add the is null.

Comment: @RahidZeynalov: it does return the row where `id` is `1` and `doc` is `'A2'` (if that's what you caled the "second row"). See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d232a9ae0c9432daf647f418bc20b790).

Comment: If subtraction between second and first c_time column is less than 3 minutes , then yes I want to see these rows too